# why file accessing method getExternalStorageDirectory() is not working on Android 10 (API 29)

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my code to access abc.jpg file in Music folder.

```
String m=Environment.getStorageDirectory().getPath();
inputStream=cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse("file:"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Music/abc.jpg"));
```

when i try to run this code it gives error.

```
File Not Found
```

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

In Android Mainfest File.